# Is there a way to check if a grid cell, NOT datagrid cell, contains an object

Tags: c#, wpf-grid

I'm assigning textboxes to cells in a grid but will like to confirm if an object already exists in the cell before assigning. Is it possible to query a row at a specific column that returns null if empty?

I could create a list of lists representing the grid which I modify as i add and remove objects but this sounds to be inefficient.

A sample code I've written:

```cs
TextBlock _text = new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = _cont,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(_colo.disciplinecolor)
                }; TextBlockStyle(_text);
                int index = SearchDate((DateTime)_dt);
                Grid.SetRow(_text, 1); Grid.SetColumn(_text, index);
                Maindispgrid.Children.Add(_text);
```

Essentially this code block is called every time the user clicks a button with the `TextBlock` added to a dated column(pre-selected by the user), and hopefully, the next available row in the column . I've tried `GetRow()` but this searched by UIElement which didn't seem to work as all `TextBlock` are created with the same name.

I might have approached this all wrong so any leads as to what I need to read up on will be much appreciated.

Basically the end result should hopefully work as this:

```cs
TextBlock _text = new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = _cont,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(_colo.disciplinecolor)
                }; TextBlockStyle(_text);
                int index = SearchDate((DateTime)_dt);
                //check for next available row at specific column index
                Grid.SetRow(_text, nextAvailableRow); Grid.SetColumn(_text, index);
                Maindispgrid.Children.Add(_text);
```

Comment: What is the problem with `GetRow()` and `GetColumn()`? That is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the children list via `Maindispgrid.Children`. For each child, retrieve the assigned `Row` and `Column` value (if assigned at all). Use this information to calculate the available row.

```
IList<int[]> indices = new List<int[]>();
foreach (var child in Maindispgrid.Children)
{
    int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(child);
    int columnIndex = Grid.GetColumn(child);
    indices.Add(new int[] {rowIndex, columnIndex});
}
// work with the "indices" list
```

Comment: The idea of this works although if implementing will have to deal with exceptions, especially if specifying child type and there are more than one type in the `Grid.Children`

Comment: @Jack You can keep the loop variable of type `var` or use the base type `UIElement`, which will be the same. The `GetRow()` and `GetColumn()` methods expect an argument of type `UIElement`, so there shouldn't be any problem getting the row index and column index. You don't need to cast or check the types of the children objects.